# x32dbg version causes crash on breakpoint

Tags: debugging, debuggers, game-hacking, game

i'm a newbie to this whole shindig, and have started with  https://gamehacking.academy. i'm finding this fun, but am getting stuck here:  when i try to apply a breakpoint using x32dbg, as in https://gamehacking.academy/lesson/2/4, and the execution reaches it; my VM crashes totally?
is this a problem with the x32dbg or something else?  thanks!
FWIW, this does not happen for 64-bit versions on the same program.